# Rest webservices in UML?

Tags: web-services, rest, uml

How do you reprensent Rest webservices in UML ?

Thanls!

Comment: What part are you trying to represent?  The behavior, actors, or architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you ask because want to communicate or document your API?

I would go for [sequence-diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/sequenceDiagram.htm). In most cases you don't need to be completely UML2 "syntax conform". Often scribbles on the whiteboard are enough to communicate your Restful api. So far I haven't seen cases where Restful api was maintained completely in UML-tools.

Another option to quick/dirty diagrams what also helps documenting Restful api over HTTP is using HTTP snippets:

```
Pattern: 
> METHOD RESOURCE-URL 
>...REQUEST-RESOURCE-PAYLOAD (if there)  
< RESPONSE-CODE
< RESPONSE-RESOURCE-PAYLOAD (if there)


Examples:

> GET /items/123
< 200

> POST /items
> ...payload(resource-representation)
< 201
```

The short text-style communication works very nice because of HTTP uniform interface (magic triangle: method, resource-url, resource-representation).